# How I can use session from php to react.js?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs

I will use the session from php that is logged in and that has an intermediary page, which will have a link to the react.js page

> How do I use the received session?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an endpoint in your php e.g. create a file "getSessionValue.php" with following content:

```
<?php
$key = $_GET['key'];

isset($_SESSION[$key]) ? echo $_SESSION[$key] : echo '';
```

In your react application, you need to make an ajax call to the this file:

for example:

```
const getSessionValue = async (key) => {
  try {
    return await axios.get(`getSessionValue.php?key=${$key}`).data
  } catch (error) {
    return undefined
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know is there an endpoint? because other people do it. I only have the session ID I received.

Comment: you need to add bit more context to your question otherwise I am just getting what exactly do you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution just add

```
credentials: 'same-origin'
```

to your AJAX request.